# Convert canvas to an image with resize

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

My code is working fine its convert canvas into image but i want to give exact height & width of an Image, My code is below

```
//Converts canvas to image
    function convertCanvasToImage(can) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = can.toDataURL("image/jpg");
            return image;
        }
```

// Converts image to canvas; returns new canvas element

```
function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    return canvas;
}
```

How can i give height & width of image on my 1st code which is convert canvas to image

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are downloading or uploading the canvas there is no need to convert it to an image. Using a DataURL for the image src uses much more memory that using the canvas element directly in place of an image.

You can set the canvas or image display size using the element's `style.width` and `height` properties

```
element.style.width = w + "px";
element.style.height = h + "px";
```